# Zodb prevent a field to be saved automatically

Tags: python, pyramid, zodb

I'm having an issue that is kind of worrying me. I have an app almost only working with traversal.

In order to get my admin paths, I have a node that gets attached to the root. on `__getitem__`, it returns `parent.__getitem__` which is my actual root. With `containment` on my views. I can check that this admin node is contained.

The problem happens when rerooting. When I do that

```
class AdminRoot(object):

    __acl__ = [
                (Allow, 'g:admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
                (Deny, 'system.Everyone', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
              ]

    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        self.__parent__ = parent
        self.__name__ = name

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        item = Mapping.__getitem__(self.__parent__, name)
        item.__parent__ = self                                                                                                                                                              
        return item
```

When `self` is affected to `item.__parent__`. It get sometimes saved as the parent node. For that reason, when doing `request.resource_url`. It will either output from the admin root or the real root.

I wish that this affectation was never saved at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you set an attribute on a `Persistent` object, it get's saved to the ZODB (provided no exception triggered a transaction abort).

In the ZODB, objects really should have only *one* parent, and thus only one, canonical URL. It is not recommended that you try and make such objects appear to have multiple URLs, at least not by manipulating the `__parent__` attribute.

Rather, you should provide a [`__resource_url__()`](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/resources.html#overriding-resource-url-generation) method to provide alternative URLs instead. You can use volatile attributes to store non-persistent information on your objects for such a method to use, perhaps.

Volatile attributes are any attribute starting with `_v_` and are ignored by the persistence engine.

Comment: Even with that, the need of the admin node was to specify `acls` on it. As it is now, people may get some random access denied on some path.

Comment: what if I make `__parent__` a property that save the parent somewhere and if not found it will return the real parent

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess there is no real good way to do that. Volatile attributes won't get deleted on each requests but only when objects are unloaded. The only real way to do that cleanly is to use urldispatch with a traverse

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: no, volatiles won't get cleaned up for you, but you *can* **set** them *anew* on each request.